# Copy 1 file content in another in c#

Tags: c#

I want to copy select parts of one file into another with C#

For example, suppose I have a file with following contents:

```
<div id="1"> contents of this div.. </div>
<div id="2"> contents of this div.. </div>
<div id="3"> contents of this div.. </div>
```

Now if I want to copy only the line `<div id="2"> contents of this div.. </div>` into a new file. Then how can i do this efficiently?

Comment: how do you identify which part of the content should be copied? (length,id,div,startswith...)

Comment: @user1400722 Can you ask a question with relevant details? Show a sample source document. Is it XHTML? Also, using words helps (u/ur doesn't show appreciation others helping you).

Comment: The fact you are wanting to output [tag:asp] does not make this an asp question

Comment: @user1400722: We need to know how your program is to decide whether it needs to copy the first, the second or the third row. If you are not able to determine that or give a criteria for that, we can't help you. As HW90 asked: Which part of the file should be copied?

Comment: I will identify it by id, like id="2", but i don`t to how to identify and how to find the end of block

Comment: @user1400722 Well, you just said "block" which is more information than you mention in the post. Just post a (stripped) sample input document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to solve this problem:

1. you can use [Regex](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) to select the part that should be copied
2. [XPath](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C) also can be used to select the content
3. If it is html you also can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

**HTML Agility Example:**

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var comments = doc.Descendants("div")
                  .Where(div => div.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "comment");
```

[Here](http://olussier.net/2010/03/30/easily-parse-html-documents-in-csharp/) you can find a overview of different methods to **parse HTML-fields** via C# (including examples)

Comment: Mandatory warning: [Don't parse HTML using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/85371)

Comment: @sehe: Could you detail why not? Is that because there are better options?

Comment: @LuisFilipe just follow the link :)

Answer (score 2):

Select the content using XPath and then export to second file.

e.g.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(data);
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='2']");
SaveToFile(node.InnerText);
```

Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for XPath example

Comment: thanks @sandeep but if u can give ur answer with little example code then it will be more helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

using a regex, for example, to extract what you want

```
<div id="2">(.*)</div>
```